# How to call a Redshift stored procedure from Lambda using boto3?

Tags: stored-procedures, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

So I'm trying to call a Redshift stored procedure from AWS Lambda but am having no luck.  I can get the Lambda function to create and drop tables if I edit the sql_text parameter to do it explicitly but I can't get it to execute my procedure on Redshift.  Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
            
    # initiate redshift-data client in boto3
    client = boto3.client("redshift-data")
    
    # parameters for running execute_statement
    secretArn           = 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-north-1:234567890123:secret:supersecret-dont-tell-a-soul'
    redshift_database   = 'dbase'
    redshift_user       = 'admin_user'
    sql_text            = 'call public.myproc(''somerandomvalue'')'
    redshift_cluster_id = 'the-redshift-cluster'
        
    print("Executing: {}".format(sql_text))
    
    response = client.execute_statement(SecretArn = secretArn, Database=redshift_database, Sql=sql_text,ClusterIdentifier=redshift_cluster_id)
    return {'statusCode': 200,'body': json.dumps('Lambdone!')}
```

Here is the response that I get Lambda

```
{
    'ClusterIdentifier': 'my-data-warehouse'
    , 'CreatedAt': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 9, 18, 1, 59, 34000, tzinfo=tzlocal())
    , 'Database': 'bidev', 'Id': '011f00d0-bf9e-45cd-bb12-b045c9504c0b'
    , 'SecretArn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-north-1:234567890123:secret:redshiftqueryeditor-super-duper-secret-secret-keeper'
    , 'ResponseMetadata':  
    {
        'RequestId': 'b2b867f0-d20c-4f2b-8e14-64942176bd6e'
        , 'HTTPStatusCode': 200
        , 'HTTPHeaders': 
        {
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'b2b867f0-d20c-4f2b-8e14-64942176bd6e'
            , 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
            , 'content-length': '270', 'date': 'Fri, 09 Jul 2021 18:01:59 GMT'}
            , 'RetryAttempts': 0
        }
}
```

Comment: You do not mention any form of error message?

Comment: That's just it.  I don't get any kind of error message.  I can submit a Drop Table and it executes just fine.  I can run the proc from Redshift and it executes without error but when I run the Lambda function the Lambda function runs without showing an error but there is no evidence of the stored procedure being executed.

Comment: Write some code in the proc to create a table and write a row or something to that table; that way at least you can see if the proc is called.  You can also look at `STL_QUERY` - that I think should show the call to the proc, although I'd need to check to make sure.  In paticular if the proc using and only using leader-node only tables/functions it might not show up (I'd need to check).  I think there's also a system table which has error messages from procedures, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your sql text so that the string is surrounded by double quotes and then the other things only have single quotes.

"call public.myproc('somerandomvalue')"

Comment: That did it!   I can't believe something so simple fixed it.  You're a life saver.  Computers are dumb.  I hate them.  I want to go home and rethink my life.